# Mod_wsgi fails to load django.core.handlers.wsgi

Tags: django, apache2, ubuntu-12.04, mod-wsgi

Ok, after 5-6 hours of trying, I give up. I have searched the web, tried all solutions suggested, but nothing is solving my problem.

**Goal:** Set up Django on my Ubuntu 12.04 VPS.

**Problem:** `Exception occurred processing WSGI script [...] ImportError: No module named django.core.handlers.wsgi` in /etc/log/apache2/error.log.

**Solutions tried:**  1) Appending the site-packages directory to the sys path in Djangos' wsgi.py file, 2) re-installing mod_wsgi, 3) making sure mod_wsgi is compiled for the same Python version as Django is installed with, 4) chmod 777 for the site-packages directory.

**Environment:**  Ubuntu 12.04 VPS, Django installation in virtualenv, Python version 2.7.3, Django version 1.6.1, mod_wsgi built from [mod_wsgi-3.4.tar.gz](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/downloads/list).

**Full error message:**

```
mod_wsgi (pid=23691): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/mySite/djangoSite/djangoSite/wsgi.py'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/var/www/mySite/djangoSite/djangoSite/wsgi.py", line 7, in <module>
     import django.core.handlers.wsgi
ImportError: No module named django.core.handlers.wsgi
mod_wsgi (pid=23691): Target WSGI script '/var/www/mySite/djangoSite/djangoSite/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.

mod_wsgi (pid=23691): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/mySite/djangoSite/djangoSite/wsgi.py'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/var/www/mySite/djangoSite/djangoSite/wsgi.py", line 7, in <module>
     import django.core.handlers.wsgi
ImportError: No module named django.core.handlers.wsgi
```

**Conf file from sites-available:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@mysite.com
    ServerName mysite.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite.com/djangoSite

    WSGIDaemonProcess djangoSite python-path=/var/www/mysite.com/djangoSite:~/Envs/myEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup djangoSite
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/mysite.com/djangoSite/djangoSite/wsgi.py

    Alias /static/ /var/www/mysite.com/djangoSite/static/

    <Directory /var/www/mysite.com/djangoSite/static>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/mysite.com/djangoSite/djangoSite>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
        </Files>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**wsgi.py:**

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append('/var/www/mysite.com/djangoSite/')
sys.path.append('/var/www/mysite.com/djangoSite/djangoSite/')

activate_this = '/root/Envs/myenv/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'djangoSite.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

**Site structure**

```
/var/www/
-- mysite.com
  -- djangoSite
    -- manage.py
    -- djangoSite
      -- settings.py, wsgi.py etc.
```

Comment: What is your Apache site .conf?

Comment: I haven't made any edits to it.

Comment: Not `apache2.conf`, but your site configuration, such as `<VirtualHost>` etc. Usually located at `/etc/apache2/sites-available/<yourdomainname>.conf`

Comment: If you have multiple python versions installed: does the python version you compiled mod_wsgi against match the python version of your virtualenv?

Comment: @adityasdarma1: Oh ok. I've updated my original post.

Comment: @sk1p: Yes, I think so. As I mentioned in the original post.

Comment: Please not to use relative path. Replace `~` to absolute path.

Comment: Have you been through any of the checks in http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/CheckingYourInstallation to determine what Python installation mod_wsgi is actually using?

Comment: I've tried, but I'm confused. Anyways, when I `/usr/sbin/apache2 -M` I get `apache2: bad user name ${APACHE_RUN_USER}`. Trying to find out what's causing this.

Comment: Ok solved that part. When I `ldd mod_wsgi.so` this is what it tells me about Python. Seems to be using the right version. `libpython2.7.so.1.0 => /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0 (0x00007f9fbd454000)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your wsgi.py, try adding this to activate virtual env:

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append('/Path_To/Virtual_Env/Project_Dir/')

#This is important if multiple apps are running (instead of setdefault)
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "app_name.settings"

activate_this = '/Path_To/Virtual_Env/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
```

In you apache config, you mainly need only(No Deamon Process required):

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/mysite.com/djangoSite/djangoSite/wsgi.py
Alias /static/ /var/www/mysite.com/djangoSite/static/
```

See from the **Create Virtual Host** section of [this link](http://thecodeship.com/deployment/deploy-django-apache-virtualenv-and-mod_wsgi/)

Comment: That gives me `IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/root/Envs/myenv/bin/activate_this.py'`. I've `chmod 777 activate_this.py` and still get that error.

Comment: Hm, I didn't `mkvirtualenv` with a project directory specified. Can I just append the path to the project to the Python path anyways?

Comment: I've added the current contents of wsgi.py in my original post. I still get permission denied :(

Comment: Try to put the virtual env outside of /root/. Your python code is executed as `www-data`. If you want to read a file, you need proper access to all directories in the path. `www-data` usually doesn't even have read access to `/root/`

Comment: @trevorDashDash you can simulate this on the shell: `sudo -u www-data bash`, then `cd /root/Envs/` should give you the same permission error

Comment: That exact syntax doesn't work on Ubuntu appereantly, but `su www-data` and then `cd /root/Envs/` gives me `can't cd to root`. As for the location of the virtual env, I think that's just where virtualenv puts all the envs per default. I'll look into it though. It makes sense that that's causing the permission error.

Comment: I'm clueless... The .virtualenvs directory is installed in /root/ per default. And www-data does not have access to that folder. So weird, everyone should be getting the same problem right?

Comment: My bad, it's working now. You guys were on the right track. I created my virtualenv in my unix users home directory and modified the wsgi file accordingly. I forgot to change the WORKON_HOME variable in my .bashrc file. I'll mark this answer as correct. Thanks a ton for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using absolute paths in your Apache2 config file. I assume you have been able to run `python manage.py shell` to get a working Django shell? I would tackle the Apache2 config file; I'm sure your issue is there.

Comment: Yes, I can run the shell. But I haven't touched the apache2.conf file. I've added a file in apache2/sites-available with the WSGI settings. And I've added this line to httpd.conf: `LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so`. What settings are you referring to to be precise?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the config file for the sites-available site you want to add, not the /etc/apache2/apache2.conf file. I assume you have installed the module, `aptitude install libapache2-mod-wsgi` and verified that the mod_wsgi is linked in /etc/apache2/mods_enabled with `apache2 en2mod wsgi`. If Can you include your sites-available configuration file in your question, there could be some clues there.

Comment: Oh ok. I've verified that mod_wsgi is enabled. I've updated my original post with the configuration file from apache2/sites-available.

Comment: But you can run `python manage.py shell` then import wsgi with `from django.core.handlers import wsgi`? If so, I think the `WSGIDaemonProcess` line may be the issue.

Comment: Yes, I can. Any ideas on what may be wrong with the `WSGIDaemonProcess` line?

Comment: First, I think you need to change `python-path=/var/www/mysite.com/djangoSite:...`  `python-path=/var/www/mysite.com/djangoSite/djangoSite:...` adding the second djangoSite, second the ~/ link may not be working as others have pointed out, try making that the absolute (full) path; but I'm not sure this is your issue, if you've tried it for other responses. Can you also add your wsgi.py file? Maybe the python path is not being set in there.

Comment: I've added the contents of wsgi.py and the django site directory structure for clarity in my original post. Still no luck :(

Comment: Bummer, I would suggest just commenting out both lines `WSGIDaemonProcess` and `WSGIProcessGroup` to be safe. Maybe add the python site-packages to the sys.path in the wsgi.py file to see if you can get it to work that way first. It certainly seems that WSGI cannot get to the Python site-packages directory. Is the site-packages/django folder owned by `www-data`?

Comment: I'll keep trying tomorrow. Thanks for the help. site-packages/django is owned by `root`.

Answer (score 0):

```
~/Envs/myEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

I think that's your problem right there: the `~` is, if it is expanded at all, expanded to the home of the www-data user. You can validate that by doing something like this:

```
import sys
print >> sys.stderr, sys.path
```

in your wsgi file; then check your error log. If it doesn't end up in the main error log, add an `ErrorLog` to your vhost to get per-vhost error logging.

Also, /root/ is not readable for the `www-data` user, you need to move your virtual env somewhere accessible.

Comment: Thanks, but I changed it to an absolute path, `/root` instead of `~`, with the same results.

Comment: Did you try to print the path from your wsgi.py?

Comment: Yes, I did now. It prints out what seems to be the correct path, including myenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages and /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages.

Comment: Is that 'myenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages' path absolute?

Comment: Yes, starting from `/root`.